# AS3 error 1119 in platformer game: "Access of possibly undefined property KeyCode through a reference with static type flash.events:Event."

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cc

i'm trying to create a simple platformer as part of an assignment, but i can't seem to move past this error. it tells me the problem lies in column 11 in all of the keyCode lines, but the tutorial i referenced uses the exact same code without a problem.

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, checkKeysDown);
function checkKeysDown(event:Event):void{
    //making the booleans true based on keycode
    if(event.keyCode == 37){
        leftKey = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 39){
        rightKey = true;
    }
    if(event.keyCode == 38){
        upKey = true;
    }
}
```

[here's a link to said tutorial](http://www.flashgametuts.com/tutorials/advanced/how-to-create-a-platform-game-in-as3-part-1/). what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're using `Event` class as argument for the function `checkKeysDown`, which doesn't have such property. It should be declared with argument of `KeyboardEvent` type.

```
function checkKeysDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void {
}
```